# Trouble using Meteor-Please to deploy to Centos/RHEL

Tags: meteor, nginx, rhel, centos7

I've been trying for sometime to use the [`mplz`](https://github.com/hellstad/meteor-please) utility to deploy and run a Meteor app. It seems (well now it seemed) simpler and more unified than Meteor Up which said it was targeted towards Debian/Ubuntu distros.

After running a successful `mplz setup` on a clean CentOS7 image, I cannot access the app. All I have ever gotten is an "nginx error!" page. In the nginx error log I saw this at first:

```
2016/03/14 17:14:47 [crit] 4997#0: *2 connect() to 127.0.0.1:3000 failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: myLocalIP, server: domain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/", host: "domain.com"
```

After doing some research I believe I fixed the permissions issue by changing the nginx user and adding the users to the appropriate groups. The website still only displayed the nginx error page, but had a new message in the `error_log`.

I am now getting a connection refused error:

```
2016/03/14 18:15:59 [error] 2489#0: *2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: myLocalIp, server: domain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/", host: "domain.com"
```

---

All I'm really trying to get done is deploy a persistent copy of my Meteor app to the server. I am not at all familiar with nginx or server-ops kind of stuff, I've mainly worked on existing websites working on features.

I would love any suggestions of how to solve this issue OR how to better or more easily deploy Meteor to a public server.

Comment: My $.02 is you are going down the right path. Keep tinkering. It looks like you have some bad config props (domain.com?).

Comment: @Bosworth99 `myLocalIP` and `domain.com` are just placeholders I put in place of the actual addresses and IP's from the `error_log`

Comment: haha. smart. Was gonna say -

Comment: check out this guide for ubuntu. Dude in the comments has a connection refused issue, and it seems to be expected at a certain point in the setup. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-meteor-js-application-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-nginx

Comment: Huh, looks like I might just abandon what I'm doing and follow that. Thanks! Do you know if an Ubuntu tutorial should work for Centos?

Comment: I would guess most of it will. The primary difference will probably be the package manager. ubuntu uses `apt-get` and centos uses `yum`. It looks like you can get `apt-get` running on centos pretty easily, if you need : http://everyday-tech.com/apt-get-on-centos/

Comment: You might also run into issues with `upstart`. Centos uses init. Might have to work around that.